# Installing node.js for Laravel on shared hosting

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, shared, nvm

An year ago I had Laravel with npm and everything running smoothly on a shared hosting as I did my npm install locally and then upload.

However, Laravel requires npm and node being installed so it can compile the assets with npm run watch or something. I'm sure there is a way since I had it last year, but since then I haven't worked with shared hosting and I can't seem to make it work now.

I tried installing through NVM, but it shows this at the end:

```
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Downloading and installing node v10.2.1...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.2.1/node-v10.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz...
######################################################################## 
100.0%
Computing checksum with openssl dgst -sha256
Checksums matched!
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.10' not found 
(required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.3' not found (required 
by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required 
by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by node)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to 
""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v10.2.1` to unset it.
```

And nothing else works from then on.

Comment: you can compile the assets locally then upload it to hosting.

Comment: yes, but the case is that I need to develop on the hosting and while developing i need to compile on every little SASS change. I know there is a way, but still can't find it.